# Adding a row in Excel on the location of the selected box

Tags: excel, vba, rows

I'm fairly new to using Macro's and code. For work I'm trying to build an Excel sheet with a macro that inserts a new row on the location of the selected box.

Sofar I have found several codes that make the new row, but all on a set location. I.e. A3. In the sheet there must be an option to add the row at any given location.

I can not find anything on the interwebs sofar.

Does someone have a solution?

Comment: Can you show us what code you have so far?

Comment: Ectualy not much. the awnser given was what I needed. but then I got stuck on the part where I also want to copy the folumas in to the newly added row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To insert a row above the selected cell use the [Range.Insert method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.insert):

```
Selection.EntireRow.Insert xlShiftDown
```